# Right View of Binary Tree

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree

**Right view of a Binary Tree is set of nodes visible when tree is viewed from right side.**

[image]

My function:

```
void rightView(Node *root)
{
if(root!=NULL)
    cout<<root->data<<" ";
while(root!=NULL)
{
    if(root->right!=NULL)
    {root=root->right; cout<<root->data<<" ";}

    else
    {
        root=root->left;

        if(root==NULL)
            break;
        else
            cout<<root->data<<" ";
    }
}
}
```

For the tree above, I obtain its right view as 58 68 63 67. However the correct answer will be 58 68 63 67 3. This happen as I traverse to 67, I see that my node does not have any left or right child and break out of the loop. However due to this behavior I missed potential nodes that lie in lower levels.
Also see that if node 3 was a child of node 67, I would obtain correct answer.

***Is there a way that I can slightly tweak my code as I was thinking to perform this operation without using Queue?***

P.S. - I am not that good expressing my problems through writing. Please don't be hostile.

Comment: Your definition of right view is unclear to me, do you mean always take right node unless there is only a left? in that case I can't see how 3 should be the correct answer?

Comment: It is, in each level, choosing the node which is the first node when viewed from the right side/direction. In other words, The Right view contains all nodes that are last nodes in their levels.

Comment: so why do you think 3 should be shown, as it is not a child of 67?

Comment: Take this Image as example for left view. [link](http://www.ritambhara.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Screen-Shot-2017-12-07-at-5.50.46-AM-300x280.png). I am choosing the first node on each level which is first from the left direction.

Comment: Put your finger on the graph, then you move down as the algorithm runs, when you get to 67, there are no more children, left and right are nullptr, so the algorithm should end.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea: iterate on the depth the tree, and keep track at each iteration of all the nodes at that depth. Make sure they are sorted from leftmost to rightmost.

At each iteration: display the rightmost node data, and create the list of nodes for the next iteration.

Besides, I suggest you clean up a bit your code. As an example, here is the same code you posted but "cleaned up":

```
void rightView(Node *root)
{
    while(root!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<root->data<<" ";

        if(root->right!=NULL)
            root=root->right;
        else
            root=root->left;
    }
}
```